# Google docs or google database for user logged in

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-storage, google-chrome-app

I have to create a chrome app which will have 1000 of text boxes. Once the data is entered i want it to be viewable on other system also without using my server(just using google server).
and it should be linked to particular person who is logged into chrome. So everytime he logged into new device/machine, data sync up.

Is there any API which can help me.

Comment: Very unclear, too broad, zero research effort AND no code shown. Too many reasons to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `chrome.storage.sync` to save data that will be saved within the cloud. unfortunately, you should be sure your extension makes no more than 10 sets, writes, or clears per minute, or you will get an error.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#properties

Comment: Not just that. The quotas are also very strict per value, per item and for the number of items.